# mysql workbench do no add me the keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

i just started studying sql , my teacher told us to use mysql workbench but don't really like it. Sometimes it seems to add me foregin keys and thers, not! I'm trying to add tables with foreign key but it always tell me error! Anyone can help? Here is the code. What i'm doing wrong? This is the text of the exercise.Thank you so so much in advance, i'm trying to improve.

We want to design a database to manage the information of interest for a set of national mobile operators. The identification code, the annual turnover and the location of the registered office are of each telephone operator. For each location, the identification code, the name, the province and the region are of interest. Each user is interested in the telephone operator with whom the user has stipulated the contract, the telephone number of the user (identifier), the user's name and the cost for each second of conversation required by the contract. Of all users, also the telephone calls made by the users themselves, and of every call, the caller, the date, the cost and the hour and the minute in which it started is of interest. The same user can not start more than one call in the same minute of the same time on the same date. Each cell phone also involves the cell that managed the start of the phone call, where each cell is identified by a
unique number within the area in which it is located.
There are only two types of phone calls: "sms" and "telephony". For "telephony" calls, the duration in seconds is used, while for "sms" calls, the number of words of which the message sent is formed. For all operators and for all contracts, the cost of a "sms" call is calculated by counting each word sent as a second of conversation.

MY TABLES:

```
create table localita(
codice varchar(20),
nome varchar(20),
provincia varchar (20),
codicecella varchar (20),
regione varchar(20),
primary key (codicecella,codice)
);



create table operatori(
 idoperatore varchar(20),
 fatturato varchar(20),
 sede varchar(20),
 primary key (idoperatore),
```

constraint foreign key (sede) references località(codice)
     );

```
create table utenze(
numeroidchiamante varchar(20),
utente varchar(20),
idoperatore varchar(20),
costosec varchar (20),
chiamateeffetuate varchar (20),
numeroidchiamato varchar(20),
primary key (numeroidchiamato,numeroidchiamante, idoperatore),
constraint foreign key (idoperatore) references operatori(idoperatore)

);




create table ChiamateFonia(
chiamante varchar(20),
datechiamate varchar(20),
orario varchar (20),
chiamato varchar(20),
costo varchar (20),
durata varchar (20),
numcella varchar (20),
codiceidcella varchar (20),
primary key (datechiamate,orario),
constraint foreign key (chiamante) references utenze(numeroidchiamante),
constraint  foreign key (chiamato) references utenze(numeroidchiamato),
constraint  foreign key  (numcella) references localita(codicecella)
) ;


create table ChiamateSms(
chiamante varchar(20),
datechiamate varchar(20),
orario varchar (20),
chiamato varchar(20),
costo varchar (20),
numparole varchar(20),
numcella varchar (20),
codiceidcella varchar (20),
primary key (datechiamate,orario),
constraint  foreign key  (chiamante) references utenze(numeroidchiamante),
constraint  foreign key (chiamato) references utenze(numeroidchiamato),
constraint  foreign key  (numcella) references localita(codicecella)
) ;
```

Comment: When  you make a FK reference to a composite primairy key (keys that is more than 1 column) you have to reference the exact columns in the correct order.

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand that we are not a "do your homework" site. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Question moved to editing. Reviewing finished. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Varchar(...) should only be used for Strings. For ID fields and Foreign Keys I would use INT(11) or BIGINT(20) for instance. It depends on how many entries you would like to have in your data base.

Comment: @ZF007 these aren't my homeworks i already did it like that and send it last week. But the teacher don't really care about giving us the result and correct us  and i know i did it wrong so i thought to ask here for help because i want to get better at it, because i think i' will need it for work in future :)

Comment: @ppijnenburg can you make an example so i can undertand better please?

Comment: @Messy I think it will be better for you to hit the books and do your own research on the web. (You will need to do this a lot when working with databases and trying to understand) I recommend you start out with the basics on the M$ docs website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/primary-and-foreign-key-constraints

Comment: @ppijnenburg do you know if there is a site like codeacademy for javascript to learn better sql?

Comment: @Messy we all did dive into books..these days lot of them are digital so... get acquainted with "ctrl-f if on windows and follow ppijnenburg's link to get your learningcurve a kick-start ;-)

Comment: @Messy codeacademy has SQL courses I believe. But start with the basics given in the link so you actually get to know the basic stuff (also see the related tasks on the bottom)